# Python: how to select columns with condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
df
    id          d1         d2          d3         a1    a2       a3
0   474     0.000243    0.000243    0.001395    bank    bank    atm
1   964     0.000239    0.000239    0.000899    bank    bank    bank
2   4823    0.000472    0.000472    0.000834    fuel    fuel    fuel
3   7225    0.002818    0.002818    0.023900    bank    bank    fuel
4   7747    0.001036    0.001036    0.001415    dentist dentist bank
```

I want to select the minimum between `d1`, `d2` and `d3` and the corresponding `a1`, `a2` or `a3`.

```
df
    id      d          a
0  474  0.000243     bank
1  964  0.000239     bank
2 4823  0.000472     fuel
3 7225  0.002818     bank
4 7747  0.001036     dentist
```

Answer (score 1):

If want select columns by lists get column name by [`DataFrame.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html), rename columns and then use [`DataFrame.lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) in [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for new columns:

```
col1 = ['d1','d2','d3']
col2 = ['a1','a2','a3']

pos = df[col1].idxmin(axis=1).map(dict(zip(col1, col2)))

df = df[['id']].assign(d = df[col1].min(axis=1), a = df.lookup(df.index, pos))
print (df)
     id         d        a
0   474  0.000243     bank
1   964  0.000239     bank
2  4823  0.000472     fuel
3  7225  0.002818     bank
4  7747  0.001036  dentist
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) here to get a *long* format dataframe, specifying `[d,a]` as stubnames. Then groupby the `id` and index taking the [`idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html) of `d`:

```
df = (pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['d','a'], suffix= '\d+', i='id', j='j')
        .reset_index().drop('j',1))
df = df.loc[df.groupby('id').d.idxmin().values]
```

---

```
print(df)

     id         d        a
0   474  0.000243     bank
1   964  0.000239     bank
2  4823  0.000472     fuel
3  7225  0.002818     bank
4  7747  0.001036  dentist
```

---

Where taking `pd.wide_to_long` as above gives the dataframe as:

```
pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['d','a'], suffix= '\d+', i='id', j='j')

              d        a
id   j                   
474  1  0.000243     bank
964  1  0.000239     bank
4823 1  0.000472     fuel
7225 1  0.002818     bank
7747 1  0.001036  dentist
474  2  0.000243     bank
964  2  0.000239     bank
4823 2  0.000472     fuel
7225 2  0.002818     bank
7747 2  0.001036  dentist
474  3  0.001395      atm
964  3  0.000899     bank
4823 3  0.000834     fuel
7225 3  0.023900     fuel
7747 3  0.001415     bank
```

Where we just need to group in the `id` and find the index of the minimum values.

Answer (score 1):

@yatu's solution was the motivator here - anywhere i see a wide to long, i test to see if stack on a multiindex can fit in :)  :

```
#set id as index:
df = df.set_index('id')

#split columns based on the numbers, and expand=True
#this converts the columns into a MultiIndex
#drop the last level, as it is empty text
df.columns = df.columns.str.split("(\d+)",expand=True).droplevel(-1)

#get indices for a min on groupby:
ind = df.stack().groupby('id').idxmin().d

#get minimum rows : 
df.stack().loc[ind].droplevel(-1)


         a          d
id      
474     bank    0.000243
964     bank    0.000239
4823    fuel    0.000472
7225    bank    0.002818
7747    dentist 0.001036
```